# How to use DropdownList when editing Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `DropDownList` in `GridView`. During the edit action, `DropDownList`s in all the rows work properly on editing (and updating).

But in certain rows, when I click edit button, it displays the following error:

> 'DropDownList3' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does
>   not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

This is the code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource4"
    DataTextField="ProvinceName" DataValueField="ProvinceName" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Province") %>'>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Table "RateCenters" is displayed in the `Gridview`, which has "Province Column".  Province column gets the source from the "ProvinceName" of the Table `ProvinceList`.

Kindly let me know the solution.

Comment: You need to show your `DropDownList` markup.

Comment: We need to see the way you're databindind your DropDownList. Apparently you're setting it's SelectedValue to somewhat not existing.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have added the markup

Comment: @jadarnel27 I have added the markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup says you are binding the `SelectedValue` of your `DropdownList` to the "Province" field in your parent datasource (the datasource for the `Gridview`)

The values in your `DropDownList` are coming from the "ProvinceName" field in your `AccessDataSource4` control.

This error means that your code is selecting a value from the `GridView` datasource ("Province" field) that does not exists in the list of values returned in the "ProvinceName" field of your `AccessDataSource4` control.

---

A quick solution to this would be to modify the "SelectCommand" of `AccessDatasource4` so that it runs the same query as your `GridView` control's datasource, but with only the one column you need ("ProvinceName") in the `SELECT` list.  That way you are guaranteed to have the same values.

Answer (score 1):

If you programatically set a value in DDL (DropDownList) that actually does not exist in the list, you will get this error.

> Scenario: You selection option 5 in DDL, but it contains only 3
>   options, for example

Tell use a little more about your code so we can investigate.